# Issue of connecting Swift to an Android BLE GATT server on Pixel 2

Tags: android, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I implemented a BLE GATT server in an android app and I am trying to connect to it from a Swift app.

I deployed the Android app on a Pixel 2 and it is found by the iOS app. However, once I call the connect() method of the centralManager, nothing happens on the iOS side - neither the didConnect nor the didFailToConnect methods are invoked whereas on the Android app, my connection callbacks are called indicating a successful connection has been established.

Can anybody help me what could possibly go wrong here?

That's my Swift Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    private var connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    // MARK: - Bluetooth Central Delegate
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if (central.state == .poweredOn) {
            print("[BT-Manager] Powered on, starting scan")
            self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [Constants.BleService_UUID], options: nil)
        } else {
            print("[BT-Manager] BT not powered on")
        }
    }

    // Called once a device is discovered
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("[BT-Manager] Found device: \(peripheral.name ?? "") - RSSI: \(RSSI)" )
        if peripheral.name == "MyPixel2" {
            print("--> MyPixel2 found")
            centralManager?.stopScan()
            connectedPeripheral = peripheral
            centralManager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }

    // Called once a connection to a device is made
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("[BT-Manager] Connection to \(String(describing: peripheral.name)) successfull")
        // connectedPeripheral = peripheral

        // set the VC to be the delegate and discover required service
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices([Constants.BleService_UUID])
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error connecting to peripheral with error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    // MARK: - Bluetooth Peripheral Delegate
    ////////////////////////////////////////

    // Called once a service is discovered
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let services = peripheral.services else {
            return
        }

        for service in services {
            print("Discovered service: \(service)")
            // discover the characteristics for this service
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }

    // Called once a characteristic is discovered
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error discovering characteristics: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
            return
        }

        print("Found \(characteristics.count) characteristics!")

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            print("Discovered characteristic: \(characteristic)")
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Android code:

```
/* ======================================================================================== */
/* ========================================= SETUP ======================================== */
/* ======================================================================================== */

private void setupBLE() {
    mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    if (!checkBluetoothSupport()) {
        // TODO: abort
        return;
    }

    // Register for system Bluetooth events
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mBluetoothReceiver, filter);
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is currently disabled...enabling");
        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth enabled...starting services");
        // start advertising and server
        startAdvertising();
        startServer();
    }
}

private boolean checkBluetoothSupport() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Bluetooth is not supported");
        return false;
    }
    if (!getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Bluetooth LE is not supported");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF);

        if(state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
            Log.d(TAG, "BT is ON");
            startAdvertising();
            startServer();
        } else if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) {
            Log.d(TAG, "BT is OFF");
            stopAdvertising();
            stopServer();
        }
    }
};

/* ======================================================================================== */
/* =================================== ADVERTISING ======================================== */
/* ======================================================================================== */


private void startAdvertising() {
    if(!mIsAdvertising) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting to advertise BT service...");
        mIsAdvertising = true;

        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
        if (mBluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create advertiser");
            mIsAdvertising = false;
            return;
        }

        AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED)
                .setConnectable(true)
                .setTimeout(0)
                .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
                .build();

        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
                .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(false)
                .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(MY_UUID))
                .build();

        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertiseCallback);
    }
}

private void stopAdvertising() {
    if(mBluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) return;

    Log.d(TAG, "Stopping advertising");
    mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(mAdvertiseCallback);
    mIsAdvertising = false;
}

/**
 * Callback for the Advertising
 */
private AdvertiseCallback mAdvertiseCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        Log.i(TAG, "LE Advertise Started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        Log.w(TAG, "LE Advertise Failed: " + errorCode);
    }
};

/* ======================================================================================== */
/* =================================== SERVER ============================================= */
/* ======================================================================================== */

private void startServer() {
    if (!mIsServerRunning) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting GATT server...");
        mIsServerRunning = true;

        mBluetoothGattServer = mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(getContext(), mGattServerCallback);
        if (mBluetoothGattServer == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to create GATT server");
            mIsServerRunning = false;
            return;
        }

        mBluetoothGattServer.addService(createSampleService());
    }
}

private void stopServer() {
    if (mBluetoothGattServer == null) return;

    Log.d(TAG, "Stopping GATT server...");
    mBluetoothGattServer.close();
    mIsServerRunning = false;
}

private BluetoothGattService createSampleService() {
    BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(MY_SERVICE, BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

    // create characteristic for app list
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic appList = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            MY_CHAR_1,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE
    );

    // create characteristic for spotify credentials
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic syncAccs = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            MY_CHAR_2,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE
    );

    service.addCharacteristic(appList);
    service.addCharacteristic(syncAccs);

    Log.d(TAG, "Created GATT Service with Characteristics ");

    return service;
}

/**
 * Callback for the GATT server handling callbacks for connection
 */
private BluetoothGattServerCallback mGattServerCallback = new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceAdded(int status, BluetoothGattService service) {
        Log.d(TAG, "GATT service added to server.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "BluetoothDevice CONNECTED: " + device);
            stopAdvertising();
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "BluetoothDevice DISCONNECTED: " + device);
            startAdvertising();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                             boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value) {
        if (characteristic.getUuid() == MY_CHAR_1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Write Request to CHAR_1");
            Log.d(TAG, "Got value: " + new String(value));
            mBluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, 0, "Worked".getBytes());

        } else if (characteristic.getUuid() == MY_CHAR_2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Write Request to CHAR_2");
            Log.d(TAG, "Got value: " + new String(value));
            mBluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, 0, "Worked".getBytes());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789955/4063602, the only difference seems to be that you should set the `CBPeripheral delegate` before you attempt the call to `connect` (compared to you setting it in `didConnect` which seems logic I'll give you that :)). Hope that helps.

Comment: @pbodsk thanks for your hint. Unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. Another weird thing I discovered is that it works if I deploy the app on a HTC Nexus 9 (with 7.1.1), but it does not on the pixel 2 (with 8.1.0). Might the Android version cause this behavior?

Comment: hmmm....interesting. Seems that could be the cause. Can you add some logging statements on the Android side of the fence maybe? Just to give you some clues about what happens there. Apart from that I don’t have anything remotely intelligent to offer as advice, sorry :)